# How to fix Roblox freezing when I enter a server?

Tags: technical-issues, roblox

Whenever I play Rise of Nations, everything seemed normal until I enter a server to play in. Whenever I try playing, it just freezes without warning. I even tried rebooting my laptop just now, yet it still didn't work. I did notice it's not really random too. Usually happens within a few seconds. It got so bad that I resorted to charging my laptop just to keep the game from crashing. Is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! When asking questions, please try to stay away from making it a response instead of a question (which is what is intended), as it will help users solve your problem.